# Best boilerplate for Meteor project?

Tags: meteor, boilerplate

Just started using meteor and built the first app using the to-do app tutorial.

Now I plan to use meteor for a project with bootstrap, is there a standard boilerplate available for this which gives me a file structure to work with ?

My app has a small to medium level of sophistication.

Comment: good one: https://github.com/themeteorchef/base

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io), a web scaffolding tool, to generate your Meteor projects.

1. Run `npm install -g yo` to install Yeoman.
2. Run `npm install -g generator-meteor` to install the [Meteor generator](https://github.com/Pent/generator-meteor).
3. Run `mkdir new-meteor-project && cd $_` to create a new project directory.
4. Finally, run the Yeoman Meteor generator: `yo meteor`.

This generator is able to include Iron Router and Bootstrap:

```
$ yo meteor

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Shall we include Iron Router? Yes
? Shall we include Bootstrap? Yes
   create client/client.js
   create client/lib/subscriptions.js
   create client/views/home.js
   create client/views/home.html
   create client/views/common/loading.html
   create lib/collections.js
   create public/robots.txt
   create server/publications.js
   create server/server.js
   create server/security.js
   create .meteor/.gitignore
   create .meteor/release
   create .gitignore
   create .jshintrc
   create .travis.yml
   create .editorconfig
   create LICENSE
   create README.md
   create client/routes.js
   create client/views/layout.html
   create client/styles/theme.css
   create .meteor/packages
```

If this generator does not meet your needs, you may want to [search for another one](http://yeoman.io/generators/).

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out, seems like yeoman is a massive collection of boilerplates. Also, I've started using Microscope with orionjs.